# Adding MultiPolygon GeoJSON file to Leaflet map layer

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers, mapbox

I have tried various solutions from other helpful answers on here but nothing seems to work.  Trying to add a local GeoJSON file with multiple polygons to a map via leaflet with zero success so far.

I am new to Leaflet.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
    crossorigin=""></script>    
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/leaflet-ajax-gh-pages/dist/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #mapid { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='mapid'></div>

<script>
var mapboxAccessToken = 'my_access_token';
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([20.0, 0.0], 3);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=' + mapboxAccessToken, {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("areas.geojson");       
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a sample from the GeoJson file, which I have created by merging multiple layers in QGIS. I wondered if the 'path' field might be causing issues so I've also tried using a single polygon file with only one of the original layers and no 'path' field but still no joy:

```
{
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  name: "areas",
  crs: { type: "name", properties: { name: "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
  features: [
    {
      type: "Feature",
      properties: {
        iso_a3: "BHR",
        iso_ter1: "BHR",
        name: "Bahrain",
        descriptio: null,
        timestamp: null,
        begin: null,
        end: null,
        altitudeMo: null,
        tessellate: null,
        extrude: null,
        visibility: null,
        drawOrder: null,
        icon: null,
        grouping: null,
        MRGID: null,
        GeoName: null,
        MRGID_Ter1: null,
        Pol_type: null,
        MRGID_Sov1: null,
        Territory1: null,
        Sovereign1: null,
        MRGID_Ter2: null,
        MRGID_Sov2: null,
        Territory2: null,
        ISO_Ter2: null,
        Sovereign2: null,
        MRGID_Ter3: null,
        MRGID_Sov3: null,
        Territory3: null,
        ISO_Ter3: null,
        Sovereign3: null,
        x_1: null,
        y_1: null,
        MRGID_EEZ: null,
        Area_km2: null,
        layer: "BAHRAIN",
        path: "C:/Users/My Name/My Company/R & D - Documents (1)/Areas/My Client/BAHRAIN/BAHRAIN.geojson"
      },
      geometry: {
        type: "MultiPolygon",
        coordinates: [[[[50.373287690475138, 26.418289404549846, 0.0]]]]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Made some modifications to the html file but getting the following error:

> TypeError: this.callInitHooks is not a function. (In
>   'this.callInitHooks()', 'this.callInitHooks' is undefined)

This is my new code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
    crossorigin=""></script>

    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css' />
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-ajax/2.1.0/leaflet.ajax.min.js'></script>
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #mapid { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='mapid'></div>

<script>
var mapboxAccessToken = 'myKey';
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([20.0, 0.0], 3);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=' + mapboxAccessToken, {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);


var areas = L.GeoJSON('areas.geojson'); 
areas.addTo(map);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'local'? Are you running page locally from file system or from server? Any errors in the debugger console?

Comment: Is the gemetry an edited fake geometry or a real one? It is totally invalid `geometry: {
        type: "MultiPolygon",
        coordinates: [[[[50.373287690475138, 26.418289404549846, 0.0]]]]`

Comment: Not seeing any errors in the debug and it's accessed from my file system.

I have wondered about the structure of the geoJSON.  While I know how to use QGIS and create layers etc. I'll be the first to admit that I'm no expert in what a geojson file should look like.  Will be sure to do some further research in this area.

Comment: If GeoJSON file is on your file system,  it cannot be accessed through AJAX call due to browser security restrictions.

Comment: Thank you TomazicM.  I've made some modifications below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your GeoJSON geometry has a **Z** dimension that a suppose leaflet can't handle:

[image]

You must remove the `0.0` value at the end of the array

Second, you must change the GeoJSON instantiation, the `L.GeoJSON` is the class definition and in order to use that way you must call with `new L.GeoJSON`. In Leaflet documentation they describe the function to instantiate a GeoJSON with the lowercase **G**, with that in mind the usage `L.GeoJSON(args)` became this `L.geoJSON(args)`

Third, your map view is set too far away from the described geometry, in the example bellow I have set the view to the geometry coordinates:

https://jsfiddle.net/guihig/2ks1ohwc/5/

Also most of the browsers can't find the path to local files, the files must be served by a http server.

Comment: Thank you.  I've fixed the geoJSON and am using an XAMPP server.  Everything is working fine now.